# Full background image scales up poorly on iPhone 5

Tags: html, ios, css, iphone, background-image

I have a one page website that displays background images in several divs. I used `background-attachment: fixed` to give it a pseudo parallax scrolling effect.

It works perfectly on the desktop. I now know that this doesn't work on the iPhone, so I removed this code from the iPhone version using a media query. (I can live with a fallback.) On the iPhone 5, the background images scale up to an unrecognizable view — so big that it is just pixels.

How can I resize the images so that they fit the phone's browser window? I have looked everywhere for an answer.

I removed all media queries. I even removed the background-attachment: fixed property to no avail. Here's a link to where the site is: http://www.mywebdesignstudio.net/danielleb_KKC  (I put back the background-attachment: fixed) If you look at it on an iPhone 5, the photos are too big. This works on the desktop, laptop, and tablet, but not on the phone--hence the media queries to swap out the photo to see if it would work. Feel free to look at the page source for the entire code.

Here's the CSS code:

```css
@viewport{
    zoom: 1.0;
    width: device-width;
}

body, html {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    font: 1em/1.8 "Arial", sans-serif;
    color: #777;
}


.bgimg-1, .bgimg-2 {
    position: relative;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}

.bgimg-1 {
    background-image: url("pic4ghost.png");
    min-height: 100%;
}

.bgimg-2 {
    background-image: url("radio.png");
     min-height: 550px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 767px){
    .bgimg-1 {
        background-image: url("pic4ghostMOBILE.png");
        min-height: 100%;
    }


    .bgimg-2 {
        background-image: url("radioMOBILE.png");
        min-height: 400px;
    }
}

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-width: 480px){

   .bgimg-1, .bgimg-2 {
        background-size: cover;
        background-position: center center;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }


    .bgimg-1 {
        background-image: url("pic4ghostsmartphone.png");
    }

    .bgimg-2 {
        background-image: url("radiosmartphone.png");
    }
```

Comment: Link to where this site is: http://www.mywebdesignstudio.net/danielleb_KKC

Answer (score 0):

use this and delete all other codes

```
.bgimg-1 {
background:url("pic4ghost.png") no-repeat center center fixed;
background-size:cover;
}
```

delete all other classes and media queries

Comment: I removed all media queries. I even removed the background-attachment: fixed property to no avail. Here's a link to where the site is:

Comment: I removed all media queries. I even removed the background-attachment: fixed property to no avail. Here's a link to where the site is: http://www.mywebdesignstudio.net/danielleb_KKC  (I put back the background-attachment: fixed) If you look at it on an iPhone 5, the photos are too big. This works on the desktop, laptop, and tablet, but not on the phone. Hence the media queries to swap out the photo to see if it would work. Feel free to look at the page source for the entire code.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the `background-size:` property?

Here is a code example. Please notice the first declared background will be on top of the rest.

```
// Gradient, image and flat color as a fallback;
.bgimg-1 {

background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255,0,0,0), rgba(255,0,0,1)), url("paper.gif"), black;
background-size: auto, cover, auto;
}
```

I used the standard syntax, because CSS3 is common practice on this days, If you have some need for backwards compatibility, check [[caniuse.com]](http://caniuse.com)

Comment: I tried auto, 100% and even contain. It seemed to ignore everything I did for some reason. I removed the media queries as someone suggested. I used the W3 Schools method for a pseudo parallax scrolling effect.